# regular expression in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

Hello I'm regular expression newbie in PHP

I'm try sort out a sting that I can insert data to MySQL which field is "timestamp"

```
$string1 = "7/1/2015, 19:42:52"; 
$string2 = "12/12/2015, 1:08:17"; 
$string1 = preg_replace("/\//",'-',$string); 
$string2 = preg_replace("/\//",'-',$string);
```

this step will like:

```
7-1-2015, 19:42:52
12-12-2015, 1:08:17
```

if I wnat sort out (include  ZEROFILL) sting like:

```
string1 = 2015-07-01 19:42:52
string2 = 2015-12-12 01:08:17
```

What Can I do..?

Comment: Take a look at: `sprintf()`

Comment: `\b(\d)\b`  replace with `0\1`

Comment: Why don't you use `date_parse_from_format` to parse the original strings, then `date` to print them in the format that you want? This doesn't seem like an appropriate use for regular expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick and dirty, but with the result you are already having you can do this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('7-1-2015, 19:42:52'));
```

This will give you the expected format: `2015-01-07 19:42:52`

Comment: It is always appreciated if you "accept" an answer that actually solved your problem ;)